# Remove burger menus in Eighties theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, navigation

How can I remove the burger menus in the Wordpress theme "Eighties" and replace it with a traditional navigation menu (logo left & menu right) above the header image.

I've tried teeaking the header.php and functions.php but my PHP skills are limited and I'm coming up short.

Any help would be much appreciated.

n.b. I can't just change the theme.

theme site: eighties.me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should show at least some pointers to the parts you use, otherwise others can't help you. Also, I'd suggest to ask at wordpress.stackexchange.com, the question sounds to be more suitable there (unless you provide details to make this really a *coding* issue).

Answer (score 0):

Any details on what you have tried would have helped. 
In WordPress in your css tab add the following code to hide the navigation buttons

```
.site-toggles{display:none}
```

And I suggest you use a menu plugin for your website.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/navigation

https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-level-navigation-plugin/screenshots/

Please mark this as the answer if it helps you out. Cheers.